# Неблокирующий обработчик в node.js

Tags: node.js, javascript

Я знаю что на эту тему не однократно создавались статьи и туториалы. И все же. Почему этот код может обрабатывать запросы только последовательно не смотря на то, что он построен с использованием setImmediate:

```
var http = require('http'),
replicate,
fileServer;

replicate = function (symbol, count) {
    var str = "",
        i;

    for (i = 0; i <= count; i += 1) {
        str += symbol;
    }

    return str;
};

fileServer = function (response) {
    var Klength = 1024, i = 0;

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Content-Length': 1024 * Klength
    });

    setImmediate(function f() {
        for (; i < Klength; i += 1) {
            response.write(replicate('A', 5));
            setImmediate(f);
            return;
        }

        response.end();
    });
};

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    if (request.url === '/favicon.ico') {
         response.writeHead(404);
         response.end();
         return;
    }

    fileServer(response);
}).listen(8000);
```

Та же проблема и при такой реализации:

```
fileServer = function (response) {
    var Klength = 1024 * 1024,
        i = 0,
        emiter;

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Content-Length': Klength
    });

    emiter = new events.EventEmitter();

    emiter.addListener('continue', function () {
        if (i <= Klength) {
            response.write('A');
            i += 1;

            setImmediate(function () { emiter.emit('continue'); });
            return;
        }

        response.end();
    });

    emiter.emit('continue');
};
```

Comment: дык это... - асинхронно ещё не значит паралельно.

Comment: ок, я понял. Тогда вопрос как мне тогда бороться с подобными ситуациями. Ведь их все равно не избежать?

Comment: Получается, разбиение обработчика на серию асинхронных вызовов не дает еще возможности запускать несколько его экземпляров?

Comment: смотрите, запуская процесс асинхронно, вы всего-лишь позволяете выполниться другим процессам, получившим событие. У вас какая проблема вообще ? медленный emit блокирует других клиентов или что ?

Comment: Проблема в том, что никакой другой запрос не поступает на обработку этому хэндлеру пока он не обработает предыдущий.Проще говоря после обращения к нему из одной вкладки браузера, в другой не получишь ответ пока не завершить первый запрос. Что интересно что други обработчики при этом отвечают без задержки. Вот именно этот момент мне не понятен.

Comment: т.е. пока не выполнится `response.end();` ? это странно. перепроверьте пожалуйста, оберните первый `emiter.emit('continue');` в setTimeout скажем секунд на 10.

Comment: и в таком случае приходиться ждать завершения обработки первого запроса

Comment: я только что у себя проверил 

curl http://localhost:8000/ в двух разных консолях нормально выполняется, данные идут и туда и туда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Длинные вычисления надо выносить в отдельный процесс. если у вас выполняется js-код без обращения к I/O, то будет блокировка. т.е. функция должна завершить свое выполнение, а у вас просто вызов друг из друга происходит. `setImmediate` просто модифицирует очередь вызовов, но на i/o она не прерывается и должна выполниться вся.